# ASP.Net website url resolution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have asp.net website built using MVC framework. The website is deployed using IIS. The website is http://smihit-reports.com/reporting. This is an internal website. How can i make sure whether user puts in http://smihit-reports.com/reporting or http://smihit-reports.com it gets directed to the same page

Comment: What *page* are both urls suppose to be redirected to?

Comment: Website launches fine when i type http://smihit-reports.com/reporting. But i want users to type http://smihit-reports.com/ or http://smihit-reports.com/reporting to be redirected to home page of the website

Comment: Did you try my example again ? ( I had made some changes)

Comment: @Shanks : Currently trying your way. Will mark it correct if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, I recommend the first one:

You have to use Redirect, here's an example:
(Remember to add the route at the top of your routes so that the generic routes don't match instead.)

1. Add a new Routing (in the global asax):

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       "Reporting Redirect",
        "reporting",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
   );
   ```
2. Controller redirect:

   public class ReportingController : Controller
       {

   ```
       public ActionResult Index()
       {

            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
       }
   }
   ```

Microsoft MVC routing explanation [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Comment: Trying this right now. This helped me get direction

Comment: Sorry, i had made some correction to my code, could you please try it again.

Comment: I think there is some issue with my code. currently it takes me to IIS 8 webpage even after making your change and not to my home page for reports. +1 for your solution though. It helped me understand the issue with my code

Comment: Don't forget to add the rule "routes.MapRoute(...") before the default one.

Answer (score 0):

By default http://smihit-reports.com/home is equal to http://smihit-reports.com, where "home" is controller name. If you want to change this behavior to use `ReportingController` instead of `HomeController` by default you should go to `RouteConfig.cs` class and change

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

To:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Reporting", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You are configuration http://smihit-reports.com/Reporting to be the default page.

Comment: Yes. And it is make sure that http://smihit-reports.com/reporting and http://smihit-reports.com gets directed to the same page.